# Libvips PHP: How to make WEBP file with given compression?

Tags: php, webp

I have code that converts and resize jpg to webp. One thing I can't solve: how to set compression.
Code is like that:

```
use Jcupitt\Vips;

$vips = Vips\Image::newFromFile('src_file.jpg');

$thumb1 = $vips->thumbnail_image(1200);

$thumb1->writeToFile('new_name.webp');
```

This code works and uses default compression. But I want to make file size smaller.
Tried following adjustments to code:

```
$thumb1 = $vips->thumbnail_image(1200, ['Q=2,optimize_coding']);
$thumb1 = $vips->thumbnail_image(1200, ['Q=2']);
$thumb1->writeToFile('new_name.webp', ['Q=2']);
```

and many more variants but file size doesn't change.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The solution:

```
$thumb1->writeToFile('new_name.webp', ['Q' => 2,'min-size' => true]);
```

Docs: https://libvips.github.io/php-vips/classes/Jcupitt-Vips-Image.html